# Can a function be continuous at the end points of its (closed interval) domain?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Assume $f$ has a domain of $[a, b]$. Is it possible that $f$ is continuous at $x = a$ and $x = b$?

If the definition of continuity is that the left and right limits are equal to the function at the given point, then this fails at $a$ since the left limit is undefined, and fails at $b$ since the right limit is undefined there.

On the other hand there are other questions on this site that imply that it is possible for a function to be continuous on a closed interval, so perhaps this is simply an incorrect definition of continuity that I have seen in some high school text books.

Comment: Your definition of continuity is incorrect. Continuity on a point does not imply that right and left limits are equal: it implies that $IF$ they exist, they are equal.

Comment: In a Calculus textbook (Stewart), they mention that $f$ is continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$ when they talk about the mean value theorem. They are referring to continuity from the right (or left) at the endpoint $a$ (or $b$).

Answer (score 6):

Your definition is correct only for interior points of the domain. For end points of the domain, the limit to be considered is the corresponding one-sided limit.

A [couple](http://people.math.sc.edu/meade/Bb-CalcI-WMI/Unit1/HTML-GIF/LimitContinuity.html#MapleAutoBookmark7) of [references](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~reinholz/ed/08sp_m160/lectures/continuity.pdf).

Comment: Can you please give a reference for this, or an explanation for why this should be the case?